# How can i make this auto play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery and pretty much 80% of this isn't my code I'm just using it to learn how to make sliders but i would really appreciate if someone could help me by telling me what i could do to make this slider work automatically the moment the page is loaded. Also just as an extra is it possible to make it so when slide_index == 16 the slide will rotate normally rather than rotating backwards until the first image. Thanks :P

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="slider">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img5.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img6.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img7.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img8.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img9.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img10.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img11.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img12.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img13.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img14.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img15.jpeg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img16.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="img17.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider {
width: 60%;
overflow: hidden;
height: 607px;
position: relative;
border: 5px #000000 solid;
margin-left: 20%;
}

.slider ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
width: 1700%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}

.slider li {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 33.333333%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.slider li img {
border: none;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
.slider button {
position: absolute;
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;
outline: none;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 13%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #fff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
height: 100%;
}

.slider button.prev {
left: 0;
font-size: 30px;
}

.slider button.next {
right: 0;
font-size: 30px;
}

.slider button:hover, .slider button:active {
opacity: 1.0;
```

}

**JQuery:**

```
    $(function() {

var ul = $(".slider ul");
var slide_count = ul.children().length;
var slide_width_pc = 100.0 / slide_count;
var slide_index = 0;

ul.find("li").each(function(indx) {
var left_percent = (slide_width_pc * indx) + "%";
$(this).css({"left":left_percent});
$(this).css({width:(100 / slide_count) + "%"});
});

setInterval(function() {
    console.log("prev button clicked");
    slide(slide_index - 1);
  }

  function() {
    slide(slide_index + 1);
    if (slide_index == 16) {
      slide(slide_index == 0);
      ul.animate({
        "margin-left": margin_left_pc;
      }, 400);
    }
  },500 );

function slide(new_slide_index) {

if(new_slide_index < 0 || new_slide_index >= slide_count) return; 

var margin_left_pc = (new_slide_index * (-100)) + "%";

ul.animate({"margin-left": margin_left_pc}, 400, function() {

slide_index = new_slide_index

});
}
});
```

Comment: slides with fixed width?

Comment: I have no clue how to change this stuff I'm new to Jquery, feel free to comment some better code to make a automatic image slider :P I would really appreciate that I can't find much help on the topic just using sites.

Comment: main idea: change 'left' position of ul (index * liWidth) inside setInterval, when index==16 make it 0

Comment: erm..... you're talking foreign to me. Could you put that in code so I could copy and paste it that way I can read it and understand/learn what you mean :P

Comment: Hey Ivan please help me. I'm honestly so stuck I just can't figure it out and you sound like you know what you're talking about.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7jfwyty9/

Comment: Thanks! Thats requires a lot less code, but is it possible to make it work automatically?

Comment: look at the answer

Comment: any success with it?

Comment: haven't tried since I was learning something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jfwyty9/1/)

Use `setInterval` to begin sliding, and `clearInterval`+`setInterval` to reset timer after click

Answer (score 1):

To your first question: From what I understand you want to have your slider slide automatically even when no button is clicked. For that you should create an interval:

```
var sliderInterval = setInterval(function() { moveRight(); }, 3000);
```

3000 equals 3 seconds here, feel free to customize that.

Comment: Thanks for your time but i posted the wrong bit of code, I'm not using that one anymore. But thanks :)

Comment: Well, you can essentially keep the line of code. You should only exchange `moveRight();` for the stuff you do when the `.next` button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(".slider .prev").click(function() {
console.log("prev button clicked");
slide(slide_index - 1);
});

$(".slider .next").click(function() {
slide(slide_index + 1);
if (slide_index == 16){
slide(slide_index == 0);
ul.animate({"margin-left": margin_left_pc}, 400);
}
});
```

To:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("prev button clicked");
    slide(slide_index - 1);
  }

  function() {
    slide(slide_index + 1);
    if (slide_index == 16) {
      slide(slide_index == 0);
      ul.animate({
        "margin-left": margin_left_pc
      }, 400);
    }
  },500 );
```

---

What I did was instead of making the functions run when the slide is clicked on, I made it where it runs the functions every half second. To change the amount of time before each slide changes you need to change the number that say 500 at th end between the two types of brackets. Hope this helped.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time and help! However, it doesn't seem to be working. Should I post my whole code (HTML, CSS & Jquery)?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful if you could post your html too. You can edit it into the original post.

Comment: Done that. By the way I really appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: So to my understanding you are trying to get the img.jpg photos to show up, but the way you are trying to access the images are wrong. It is possible to use images that are saved in your computer or from a database, but the easiest way would be to upload the images to a image hosting website like Imgur and the for the src=, put the url in between quotes.

Comment: ok I will sure do thatt in just a sec. But that doesn't help my current issue because the slider still isn't working and surely that can't be why?

Comment: I'm sorry I mixed up what post I was commenting on. Now that you posted the whole code I will look to see what could be going wrong for the sliding.

Comment: Haha, oh well I did that anyway :) Thanks man it means a lot.